# Returning all values in rows that contain specific text

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I am in the process of making a Budget for my Family. I would like to be able to make a list of everything we buy:
e.x.

ROW A| ROW B |  ROW C           | Row D

Date | Amount| Type of purchase | Account

Jan 1| $12.00| Groceries        | Visa Debit

Jan 2| $2.20 | Office Supplies  | Credit card

Jan 3| $10.00| Groceries        | Credit Card

Is there a way for me to have a cell that calculates the amount spent in each catagorie? (looks at row C for groceries and then returns the sum of all that was spent on groceries) I want to get totals for how much I spend in each category as well as from which account they are coming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you label as "Row" is called a "column" in spreadsheets. Vertical columns have the different data types and categories and each horizontal row has an item in your table, e.g. a purchase you made.

With such a setup you can easily create a pivot table to sum (or count or otherwise aggregate) the data, for example all spend by month, or spend broken down by account or purchase type.

Just a quick run down: Make sure your data does not have empty row or empty columns. It is helpful to turn your data into an Excel Table object with Insert Table. Then you can insert a pivot table with Insert > pivot table.  In the Pivot table pane pull field names (the column titles) into the rows and columns area and into the values area if you want to sum/count/average.

[image]

Pivot tables are quick to set up and easy to learn. There are many, many web sites and tutorials out there that explain them. This one is a good start: http://www.contextures.com/CreatePivotTable.html